# Formula Field Not growing when in the same page footer as a sub-report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-9

Basically, I have a formula that runs while printing records, that can print 0-3 rows using chr(13) and global stringvars to form a final string (tried with chr(10) and chr(13)), in the same page footer as a sub report that can have anywhere from 0 rows to above 3. Both are set to "Can grow" however the formula field never grows past the sub-report.

I'm using Crystal Reports 9.

I also tried using a box around the formula leading from the previous page footer to another page footer.

Here's my formula

```
WHILEPRINTINGRECORDS;
global stringvar WD;
global stringvar ADV;
global stringvar NASC;
stringvar final :="";

IF WD <> "" AND ADV <> "" AND NASC <> "" THEN final := WD  + Chr(13) + chr(10) +  NASC + Chr(13) + chr(10) + ADV
ELSE IF WD = "" AND ADV <> "" AND NASC <> "" THEN final := NASC + Chr(13) + chr(10) + ADV
ELSE IF WD <> "" AND ADV = "" AND NASC <> "" THEN final := WD + Chr(13) + chr(10) + NASC
ELSE IF WD <> "" AND ADV <> "" AND NASC = "" THEN final := WD + Chr(13) + chr(10) + ADV
ELSE IF WD = "" AND ADV = "" AND NASC = "" THEN final := "";
final
```

And here's a sample of one of one of the formulas that set the stringvars, they all follow the same method.

```
WHILEPRINTINGRECORDS;
global Stringvar ADV;
global Stringvar Status;

if({COLUMN1}="EX" 
  OR {COLUMN1}="ADV" 
  OR {COLUMN1}="CR" 
  OR {COLUMN1} = "DES" )
 THEN ( ADV := "#     - EXEMPT";  Status := "Status"; "#") ELSE ""
```

Comment: Is the sub report property set to can grow

Comment: Yes it is, as well as the fields within it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Each Subreport has it's own details section and if your fields are set there, it shows results for all of your rows, even if you put it in footer. Conversely, a formula that is set in a footer (page or report) works in an aggregate form, because footer is supposed to be used only for aggregate result (max,min,sum etc). If you put a formula in footer and you edit it to return a field value or something that it has to do with a field's value, then it will return result only for the first row of your select (like TOP 1 in SQL), I think.

Of course I am not completely sure because you have not displayed any results or your schema, but your case seems much like it